# Can I use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a VPN on the remote computer?

Tags: windows, vpn

I want to be able to use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to my "home PC" from my laptop remotely, and then once that connection is established, I want to open a Cisco VPN connection on the "home PC".  Is that possible?  Or will the process of opening a VPN connection on the "home PC" disrupt my Windows Remote Desktop connection?

If it's relevant, both the laptop and the home PC are windows 7 (Pro and Ultimate, respectively).

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I cannot just open the Cisco VPN connection on my laptop. It has to do with inane IT policies at my company.

Thanks, any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Whats happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try: http://www.teamviewer.com/
It's the simple solution...

> TeamViewer is a proprietary computer software package for remote
>   control, desktop sharing, online meetings, web conferencing and file
>   transfer between computers. The software operates with the Microsoft
>   Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, iOS, and Android operating systems. It is
>   possible to access a machine running TeamViewer with a web browser.
>   While the main focus of the application is remote control of
>   computers, collaboration and presentation features are included.
>
> Other similar programs which *currently* exist include GoToMyPc,
>   LapLink Everywhere and LogMeIn.

Blurb Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer)

Comment: Could you please add some details about Team Viewer to your post? -- Specifically how it would help solve the problem described in the original post.  This will help avoid link rot on the site in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: If the teamviewer.com link rots, I'll be very sad :)

Answer (score 1):

You can chain RDP sessions - I've had 3 before and had no problem or lag (albeit through powerful internet lines!). In other words, VPN to one workstation and from there start RDP to connect to a local machine. I've even then opened another RDP session (IT debugging - it made sense at the time).

From memory, I was also using different versions of the OS - I think it was XP, W7 and Server 2008.

Comment: I've experience with this same technique.  Didn't have VPN credentials saved on my phone while I was at a remote location. I VNC'd into home computer, VNC'd into another home computer (one with the VPN credentials saved), made the VPN connection so that I could then VNC into corporate router and setup the VPN tunnel for the location I was physically at.

Comment: I didn't know it could be done via the phone! Thank you for sharing this. +1

Comment: A little tedious controlling all those VNC sessions with an iPhone, but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can RDP to your home PC.  You would need to forward the necessary ports on your home router/firewall to connect.  There are 2, but I cant remember what they are off the top of my head.  However, *this means your RDP connection would be unencrypted and insecure*.  You could then launch your VPN client.  This may break your RDP session, but you would just have to reconnect and you would be fine.

Comment: Actually RDP has built-in encryption.